# Can not write to a file php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file, fopen

I'm getting an error while writing a string to a file with PHP. The code is below.

```
$this->filecontent = '<?php
    require "../db_credintial.php";
    $currentdir = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
    $basename = basename($currentdir, ".php");
    $updateauthSQL = "UPDATE `member` SET `mailconfirmed` = '1' WHERE `member`.`identifier` = '".$basename."'"; // this is where error is generator when writing the whole string

    if($conn->query($updateauthSQL))
    {
        echo "email is now validated";
    }
    else{
        exit($conn->error) ;
    }
    
    ?>'; // this is the whole string



    $this->myfile = file_put_contents($this->filename,$this->filecontent); // create the new file
```

the filecontent variable has a string value but within the string, there is a SQL statement that includes other variables. I'm getting error at this point when writing the php as a string. I'm assuming the problem is with the quote mark. Can somebody help?

Comment: You must escape all `'` chars if you use this char to open your string definition. At the same time, your code is creepy and you should probably change your business logic to prevent creating strange PHP files dynamically.

Comment: Hi i have tested without the single quote but in that case my program wont work. is there any way to continue with the single quote ?

Comment: Escaping means you place a `\\` right before the unescaped char. Read PHP basics on php.net

Comment: cheers buddy it worked thanks